# Function returning dataframe overwrites previous variable assignment

Tags: python, pandas

From a function, I'm calling another function that returns a dataframe which returns a new dataframe each time and assign it to a variable, test_1. In the same function I call the other function a second time and assigned the returned dataframe to another test_2. When I print both test_1 and test_2, they are both the same dataframe.

Here's my code:

```
def population(count, curve_set_origin):
    test = []
    test_1 = individual(1, curve_set_origin)
    print(test_1)
    test_2 = individual(2, curve_set_origin)
    print(test_2)
    print([test_1, test_2])
    return test
```

On line 4 the dataframe returned by test_1 is different than the dataframe returned by test_2 on line 6 but on line 7, the dataframe in test_1 and test_2  are the same.

```
# Individual
def individual(name, curve_set_origin):
    new_curve = pd.DataFrame
    curve_set_origin.iloc[:,9:] = curve_set_origin.iloc[:,9:].apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: y + get_random() if y != 0 else 0), axis=1)
    new_curve = curve_set_origin
    new_curve['name'] = name
    return new_curve

# Define random number between XX and XX with 4 decimal
def get_random():
    while True:
        val = float(random.randrange(-9999, 9999)/10**(random.randint(5,9)))
        if val != 0:
            return val
```

`curve_set_origin` is a dataframe.

Comment: try `df.copy(deep=True)`. You probably set a pointer from one df to the other

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, `test_1` and `test_2` are not copy of each other.

Comment: Ok, then please provide us with an [cmve] of your code. It's hard to get what you want to do if we don't know what the functions you are calling are.

Comment: I've added some code. The idea is modify the values in `curve_set_origin` randomly.

Comment: Columns 1-8 should still be the same. Are you sure that you are not just looking at that unchanged columns?

Comment: `new_curve = pd.DataFrame`  =>   `new_curve = pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: That did it! Thank you.